# Matlab about insert number inside array

Tags: arrays, matlab, insert

I want to insert two different number into one element for example when `A(1,1)=1` and I want to insert 2 into `A(1,1)` which will become `A(1,1)=1,2` not to be overwritten Matlab system.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe another approach would be better. Like storing two matrices.

Comment: What is your overall goal here? What are you going to do with this matrix later? There are many options e.g. add a dimension, use cell array, use struct array...

Comment: `A(1,1) = "1,2"`could work.. You just have to `split` the data later on to get the two numbers. (It is stored as a string though)

Comment: Why do you want to store two values in one element?

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using a cell structure to store these doubles for this?

```
A{1,1}=1;
A{1,1}(1,end+1)=2;
```